# java classcast exception

Tags: java, xml

i have problems in converting an XML document type into a Document object..
this is the piece of code

```
Document doc=null;
doc = (Document) parser.parse(sourceFile);
```

for this line 2 it throws java classcast exception..

without the typecast it shows error as

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.w3c.dom.Document to javax.swing.text.Document
```

how do i now typecast properly? any suggestions??

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there's a collision in the unqualified names.

That is, as a result of your `import` statements, the unqualified name `Document` refers to `javax.swing.text.Document`, but you really need `org.w3c.dom.Document` instead (that's the type that the parser returns).

You can fix this by using the fully qualified name:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) parser.parse(sourceFile);
```

Or, you can also specifically `import` the particular `Document` as follows:

```
import javax.swing.text.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

//...

Document doc = (Document) parser.parse(sourceFile);
```

This is called the *single-type import declaration* ([JLS 7.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.1)), and it can be used to "shadow" other declarations.

Comment: @shil: can you qualify your own statement "hi i have problems in converting an XML document type into a `Document` object." -- which `Document` are you talking about here? Because if it's `javax.swing.text.Document` then unfortunately no, you can't cast it. You'd have to do a more elaborate conversion enabled by libraries (not by the Java language). See Michael's answer.

Comment: yeah its javax.swing.text.Document.. and i couldn figure out what i should do, from micheal's answer.. could you elaborate?

Comment: @shil: What would you like to do with the `swing.Document`? Can you elaborate further? Maybe edit the question with your intent.

Answer (score 2):

Those two interfaces have the same name, but are totally unrelated. You cannot cast between them - it doesn't make sense as they represent quite different concepts (OK, theoretically, you could have a Swing component that displays XML trees and uses a DOM Document as its model, but I don't think that's what you have).

What you probably want to do is to take the unparsed XML and call [`setText(xmlText)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) on the swing component you want to display it with.

Comment: +1, turns out that's what OP intended to do after all. You may want to take over from here.

Answer (score 1):

Is your application a Swing application or not?

You are probably using an IDE which you automatically let organize the imports in your source file. The IDE added an import for `javax.swing.text.Document` instead of `org.w3c.dom.Document`. This is something I've encountered myself often while using the Eclipse IDE.

What you have to do: Remove this line from the top of your source code file:

```
import javax.swing.text.Document;
```

Replace it with:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

Comment: Jesper: the `import` turns out to NOT be the problem: OP actually wants to convert a w3c `Document` to a Swing `Document` somehow.

Comment: Ok. Well, that's ofcourse not easy, because `org.w3c.dom.Document` and `javax.swing.text.Document` are two totally different things, even though they are both called `Document`.