# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; when trying to get colum values to a list by Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm developing a spring web application with Hibernate. I have faced an error when getting column values from a table to a list. But this error keeps coming. Please help me put. Thanks in advance.

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GetProjectsDaoImpl implements GetProjectsDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateUtilImpl  hibernateutilimpl;

    public List<Projects> getProjects() {

        String sql = "select project_id from project";

        List<Object[]> projectObjects = hibernateutilimpl.fetchAll(sql);

        List<Projects> projectsList = new ArrayList<Projects>();

        for(Object[] projectObject: projectObjects) {
            Projects project = new Projects();
            String id = (String) projectObject[0];

            project.setProjectId(id);

            projectsList.add(project);
        }
        return projectsList;
    }

}

@Repository
public class HibernateUtilImpl implements HibernateUtil {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public <T> Serializable create(final T entity) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    public <T> T update(final T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public <T> void delete(final T entity) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public <T> List<T> fetchAll(String query) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(query).list();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java classcast exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757034/java-classcast-exception)

Comment: did you try in your method getProjects() change Object[] to String ?

Comment: `hibernateutilimpl.fetchAll(sql)` returns a `list<String>` in your case

Comment: by any chance is the id value coming out as an `Integer` and not a `Object` it could also be that the library is setting type based on column type information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have following suggestions. First change:

```
List<Object[]> projectObjects = hibernateutilimpl.fetchAll(sql);
```

to:

```
List<Object> projectObjects = hibernateutilimpl.fetchAll(sql);
```

Next, change:

```
for(Object[] projectObject: projectObjects) {
    String id = (String) projectObject[0];
```

to

```
for(Object projectObject: projectObjects) {
    String id = (String) projectObject;
```

The above change is needed because you are selecting only a single column. `Object[]` is used only when selecting more then one column.

Comment: Thanks. this works for a single column. but what if i want to select several columns?

Comment: Hi, for multiple columns the original code your wrote should work, let's say you have project_id and project_name, change your sql to fetch 2 columns, to get the value of second column do String project_name = (String) projectObject[1];

Comment: In addition to above if you are selecting all columns then you can do List <Projects> projectObjects if Projects has all the fields corresponding to columns in PROJECT table...

Comment: @Michael0x2a - Thanks for editing my answer, could you please tell me where can I find the instructions about how to format the content/code that we write.

Comment: @deepakl, panel where you edit or write the "Answer" has basic formatting  toolbar; use that to make your post more readable.